# Wanted to know why doesn't the print statement in child process is not printing

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, parent-child, child-process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = fork();

    if (rc < 0)
    {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (rc == 0)
    {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);

        int ret = open("./out.log", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            printf("Failed to open file for stdout redirection\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        char *myargs[2];
        myargs[0] = strdup("ls"); // execute ls command
        myargs[1] = NULL;

        int status = execvp(myargs[0], myargs);
        if (status == -1)
        {
            printf("execvp: failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Child: Finished\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Parent: Finished\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: If you mean `printf("Child: Finished\n");`, its because `execvp` succeeded, and thereafter *replaced* the current process. [Read the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp). E.g., there is no spoon.

Comment: To get the child _program_ (what is executed by `execvp`) to output to the target file (e.g. `out.log`), just before the `execvp` we need to attach `stdout` for the program to the file. So, we need to do: `dup2(ret,STDOUT_FILENO); close(ret);`